# How do I upload a file via HTML before passing it to a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, file, upload

So I'm very new to the world of web development and have a project I'm working on in which I'd like a user to upload a .txt file before being returned another file containing an edited version of their file. The difficulty I'm finding is that JS seems to be limited in its file handling ability.

So far the idea is that I have an HTML form through which the user uploads their file and a .js function call, like such:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    <input type="file" name="randomfile" id="rand">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fileEditor.js">
</script>
```

My question is, how do I utilize the file contents with the .js function and how do I return a new file from that javascript? Is it even possible?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but HTML forms refresh the page. You'll want to submit the text file via an AJAX request if you don't want the page to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you would want to use the Javascript File Reader.

First, you'd want to get the file from the input element:

```
//Gets files from document element
var files=document.getElementById('rand').files;
//Selects first File and assigns it to file
var file=files[0];
```

Then you'd want to create the filereader:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
```

Then you'd want to tell the FileReader what to do when it's done reading your file. This can be any function you want, and it's in the onload function that you'd want to do anything you want to the file.

```
reader.onload=function(evt){
    //Prints contents of first file to the console
    console.log(evt.target.result)
}
```

Finally you'll want to tell the filereader to actually read the file:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
```

If you want more info, you can find info [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=ztY7N2UG-Aw).

Edit:
Also looking at your code the page will refresh by default. I'd recommend adding the function to read the file on the onclick on the submit button.

I have an example of all of the above at http://jsfiddle.net/fdxw2p5f/1/

Comment: I can see this method works for what I need to do, though I was wondering what your <span> tag with the id="contents" actually does in the example provided.

Comment: It'll drop the contents of whatever file you uploaded. Try uploading a text file. It doesn't work for every type of file, but it should for most .txt files.

Comment: Where do you call the script from the HTML? It's not working as intended with my code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I didn't make that very clear in the code. It's the line `document.getElementById('sub').onclick=readFile;` that sets it so the function "readFile" is executed when you click on the selected button. You could also add it inline if you want with `<input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" onclick="readFile()"/>`.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. I wasn't sure as I assumed you'd have to make a call in HTML. Is there any way this code can be used to take the contents of the file given and make a new file? I know standard JS can't handle files, but if it used some of the NodeJS library?

Comment: Well it can with certain libraries. I use Filesaver.js. It's pretty easy to use,

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: **JavaScript** is a client-side scripting language, i.e., it works only on the client's machine. If you are using **JS** to process a file, that means you are not *uploading* it, because uploading refers to sending a file to the server.

Comment: it's 2022 and it's been a while JavaScript can be used on the server with node